# how does matrix theory yield the Laplace equation from the Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: matrices, cauchy-riemann-equations

In her paper "How I became a torchbearer for matrix theory" Taussky writes:

> In the late thirties Isuddenly realized that the Cauchy-Riemann
> equations and the fact that they imply the Laplace equation can be
> expressed via matrix theory and can be connected with the fact that
> the field of complex numbers has no zero divisors.

how can matrix theory yield the Laplace equation from the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [Wirtinger derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives)

$$\partial_z = \frac{1}{2} \left( \partial_x - i \partial_y \right)$$
$$\partial_{\bar{z}} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \partial_x + i \partial_y \right)$$

acting on smooth functions $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, where we tacitly identify $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$ via $z = x + iy \mapsto (x, y)$. Write $z = x + iy, \bar{z} = x - iy$, regarded as smooth functions $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. It is a pleasant exercise to check the following:

1. $\partial_z z = 1, \partial_z \bar{z} = 0$.
2. $\partial_{\bar{z}} z = 0, \partial_{\bar{z}} \bar{z} = 1$.
3. $f$ is holomorphic iff $\partial_{\bar{z}} f = 0$ (so this condition is equivalent to the Cauchy-Riemann equations) and anti-holomorphic iff $\partial_z f = 0$.
4. The Laplacian $\Delta = \partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2$ can be written $\Delta = 4 \partial_z \partial_{\bar{z}} = 4 \partial_{\bar{z}} \partial_z$. Hence it immediately follows that any holomorphic or anti-holomorphic function is harmonic.

Presumably this is what Taussky is referring to. The conceptual innovation here is the idea of treating differential operators as algebraic objects in their own right; they form an infinite-dimensional ring of linear operators generalizing the familiar concept of finite-dimensional matrices, which maybe is why Taussky calls this "matrix theory" (this is not exactly a standard term so I don't know what Taussky is using it to mean).

To get the above factorization we need to know that 1) the partial derivatives commute, and 2) that over $\mathbb{C}$ we can factor a sum of two squares. However, I don't believe this argument really uses that $\mathbb{C}$ is a field, so I don't know what Taussky has in mind there. Similar factorizations are available involving [Clifford algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation#Dirac%27s_coup) in higher dimensions, and Clifford algebras aren't division algebras in general.